# Using prebuilt static library

Tags: android, android-ndk

I looked at every question on SO and google, but still no luck.

I've been given a prebuilt static library libdroid.a that i need to use in my application.

I've tried putting it in the jni folder with an Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libdroid
LOCAL_LDLIBS := libdroid.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

and calling it in java like

```
static {
        System.loadLibrary("droid");
    }

     public static native int droidCall(int num1, int num2);
```

but when I run the application i get

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load droid: findLibrary returned null
```

I'm thinking it's because it's not suppose to go in the JNI folder? But I tried in obj and libs folder too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create your own shared library (`*.so`) which will be calling functions you need from that prebuilt static library. Then you load this `.so` library with `System.loadLibrary` and use its native functions

Comment: I'll try it out and report back!

Comment: Note that you will need to put the native method declaration in Java code in the same package and class name as encoded in the name of the exported native function, or else wrap it in your own native library.  And this is assuming that the library in question was even built for android.

Comment: Worked! But why can't we just use a static library directly? Sorry, im new to ndk and c/cpp